# Communiate ROS with JAUS SDK

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All
I am curious if anyone has build the communication between any Jaus(Joint Architecture for Unmanned Systems) SDK with ROS. Even no one does, any suggestion about where and how to star will be appreciated. Thanks.
Jayson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9879/communiate-ros-with-jaus-sdk/) by [jayson ding](https://answers.ros.org/users/492/jayson-ding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We at CWRU did a little bit with JAUS+ROS for IGVC 2010. See [cwru_jaus](https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/tree/master/cwru_experimental/cwru_jaus). That code relies on having the appropriate JAUS SDK installed (either OpenJAUS or JAUS++, I honestly can't remember; shouldn't be too hard to figure out from the code or makefiles/CMakeLists).

That code was basically supposed to carry out the interoperation required by the JAUS competition in IGVC 2010, so looking into those rules should give you an idea of what cwru_jaus was trying to accomplish.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask and I'll try to answer. Keep in mind that that code is experimental and not really documented.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1